# Make first 3 characters in cell fixed for entire column, for e.g PRT and any new input in these cells for will populate after the PRT so PRT1253

Tags: excel, formatting

I would like to fixed the first 3 characters in a column cell for the entire column and any subsequent input in that column will only begin after the first 3 characters.

For e.g every cell in the column will have fixed "ACT" for type of policy and then I can manually input the policy number 112929 it will automatically fill as "ACT112929" and next cell down will be "ACT112930" etc

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom format for the cells:

```
"ACT"#
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: If you think the answer is helpful, then click on the check mark so that people know your question has been answered